# disassociate EIP and then convert to vps eip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-elastic-ip

I have an eip that I want to convert from scope EC2-classic to VPC. Can I disassociate, convert to VPC eip, and then just re-associate with the same ec2 instance? I'm not sure if I will be able to reattach it to an instance, not in the VPC.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/announcing-elastic-ip-address-migration-from-ec2-classic-to-ec2-vpc/

Answer (score 0):

This [knowledge base article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ssm-migrate-ec2classic-vpc/) covers converting VPC Classic EIPs to VPC EIPs. I suggest using the link as AWS tend to keep documentation up to date, whereas the post below may become out of date over time.

1. Open the AWS Systems Manager console, and then choose Automation from the navigation pane.
2. Choose Execute automation.
3. On the Owned by Amazon tab, in the Automation document search box, enter MigrateEC2Classic.
4. Select the radio button for the AWSSupport-MigrateEC2ClassicToVPC document, and then choose Next.
5. Under Input parameters, for InstanceId, enter your source EC2-Classic instance ID.
6. For AutomationAssumeRole and TargetInstanceType, choose your required parameters. By default, TargetInstanceType is set to t2.xlarge.
   Note: For more information about the IAM permissions that are required for AutomationAssumeRole to successfully run the Automation, see AWSSupport-MigrateEC2ClassicToVPC.
7. (Optional) For DestinationSubnetId and DestinationSecurityGroupId, enter your subnet ID and VPC security group ID.
   Note: If these fields are left blank, then the Automation selects a random subnet in the default VPC. Security groups that are attached to the source instance are copied to the VPC and used to launch the target instance.
8. For MigrationType, select Test or CutOver.
9. If you select CutOver for MigrationType , then set the following parameters:
   SNSNotificationARNForApproval: Enter the ARN of the SNS topic used to send Approval notifications to stop the source instance. ApproverIAM: Enter the ARN of the IAM users or roles that can approve or reject the action to stop the source instance.
10. Choose Execute.